# meta: why do I have to specify a group by clause

Tags: t-sql

Just curious why I really have to specify a group by clause since if I use a function that requiers a group by clause(can't remember the general name of those functions), eg. SUM().

Because if I use one of those I have to specify every column that doesn't use one in the group by clause.

Why doesn't sql just automatically group on all columns that isn't using an aggregation function? It seems redundant since as soon as I'm using an aggregation I'm grouping on all other columns that is not using it.

Comment: I would imagine to avoid unexpected behaviour and make things easier for the user.  But this isn't something you are really going to get a suitable answer for given SQL's long history and your inability to actually do anything to change the current situation.

Comment: True. just wonder if anyone can justify the design choices of then tsql language. Like is there somtimes where I don't have to specify the column i group by?

Comment: You *always* have to specify your grouping columns.

Comment: apparently no in MySQL - learnt something new today, as so often, whilst answering

Comment: You could specify an aggregation function with an over clause to avoid the group by. The point is that the sql engine must know the condition to aggregate on.

Comment: @user3094533 But the condition to aggregate on the sql engine already knows, since it is telling me that in the error message. It is always the columns that hasn't got an aggregate function. Or is there somtimes when that isn't true? It just seems redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably for the same reason a C compiler would not automatically assume and insert a variable declaration if you are using one that has not been previously declared. There are programming languages which do that sort of things, SQL is not one of them.

*Editors*, on the other hand, may be aware of this and at least auto-complete functionally dependent parts of the syntax for you. Oracle SQL developer will by default automatically append a `GROUP BY` clause as soon as it detects you're writing a select column list that needs it. IMO this is a pain, and I usually keep it turned off, but it will be as far as you get - on an IDE/editor level.

Edit: Based on your last comment, there is an option in MySQL (not Microsoft's T-SQL) meant to relax the rule by implementing optional feature T301 of the standard SQL99. I think this is exactly what you're after:

> MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Could not find much information on the status of this feature in future versions of T-SQL, though. The only reference is [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh544322(v=sql.105).aspx), with the very cryptic remark that T-SQL would "partially support this feature".

Comment: Ok.  Cool to know you don't need it in mySQL. Nothing that I'm really bothered by it just seems like a redundant design in the language